# What's the utility of forall if not using type class constraint?

Tags: haskell, forall

I've finished reading [the Existential Types Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types), and it compares using `forall` with using lowercase letters for defining generic types. It then says that the true usefulness of `forall` is when you use it with a type class. That is, `forall` make your function work with lots of types that adhere to some type class.

Example:

```
 data ShowBox = forall s. Show s => SB s
```

Well, I found a real worl usage:

```
spock :: forall conn sess st. SpockCfg conn sess st -> 
                               SpockM conn sess st () -> IO Middleware
<Source>
```

and you can see here, in the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.14.0.0/docs/src/Web.Spock.html#local-6989586621679091497) that it uses `forall` but with no type class constraint:

```
spock :: forall conn sess st. SpockCfg conn sess st -> 
                               SpockM conn sess st () -> IO Wai.Middleware
spock spockCfg spockAppl =
    do connectionPool <-
           case poolOrConn of
             PCNoDatabase ->
             {- ... -}
```

I'm very new to Haskell and trying to understand `forall`.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @SimonShine the question is in the title.

Comment: Presumably when the Existential Types Wikibook makes a claim about using `forall`, it is talking specifically about using `forall` to declare an existential type. So I wouldn't read much into this claim -- all it is saying is that, *for existentials*, class constraints are needed to be able to do anything interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, forget about existentials. They're a bit of a bodge – I personally never use that extension, only the strictly more general [`-XGADTs`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) when needed.
Also, allow me to use the `∀` symbol for universal quantification, which I find much more readable. (Note that it looks a bit like the `\` lambda, which is the value-level analogue of `∀`.) This requires `-XUnicodeSyntax`.

So, the signature

```
spock :: ∀ conn sess st. SpockCfg conn sess st -> SpockM conn sess st () -> IO Middleware
```

is, for all outside purposes, exactly the same as

```
spock :: SpockCfg conn sess st -> SpockM conn sess st () -> IO Middleware
```

or

```
spock :: SpockCfg c s t -> SpockM c s t () -> IO Middleware
```

When you see such a signature with explicit `∀`, the reason usually doesn't have anything to do with either `-XExistentialQuantification` or `-XRankNTypes`. Rather, they either simply found it clearer to explicitly say what are the type variables, or the definition may make use of [`-XScopedTypeVariables`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables). For example, these two definitions are actually different:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

foo :: a -> a
foo x = xAgain
 where xAgain :: a
       xAgain = x

foo' :: ∀ a . a -> a
foo' x = xAgain
 where xAgain :: a
       xAgain = x
```

`foo` doesn't compile, because both the global as well as the local signature is interpreted as implicitly quantified, i.e. as

```
foo :: ∀ a . a -> a
foo x = xAgain
 where xAgain :: ∀ α . α
       xAgain = x
```

But that doesn't work, because now `xAgain` would have to have a polymorphic type independent of the type of `x` you passed in. By contrast, in `foo'` we only quantise once, and than the `a` from the global definition is also the type use in the local one.

In the example of `spock`, they don't even use a scoped type variable, but I suspect they did during debugging and then just left the `∀` there.

Comment: The [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.14.0.0/docs/src/Web.Spock.html#local-6989586621679091497) in the question has `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` so your suspicion seems plausible

Comment: A third reason to use `forall`: you expect your function's consumers to use `TypeApplications`, and you want to fix the order of the type arguments.

Comment: ... and I now see that Will beat me to it!

Answer (score 3):

A type declaration like

```
f :: A a -> B b -> C
```

is implicitly universally quantified, i.e. means the same as

```
f :: forall a b . A a -> B b -> C
```

Both mean: `f` has a polymorphic type, where `a` and `b` can be anything (i.e. range over *all* types) . In this case the scope of the `forall` is the *whole* type expression, and it is usually left out, but it is always there, implicitly. In your example, it is written explicitly, maybe to neatly enumerate the type variables.

However, there are cases where you need the `forall` even without typeclasses: [rank-N types](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/users_guide/quantified-types.html), where the scope of the `forall` is *not* the whole type expression.

A well-known example is  used in the [`ST` monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad/ST) where you see the function:

```
runST :: forall a. (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

Note that the first `forall` can be omitted, as in the example above, but not the second. Note also that there are no typeclass constraints in the type of `runST`.

Comment: Assuming the first, redundant `forall a.` is removed, what would be the consequence/meaning of removing `forall s.` too (or at least attempting to do so)?

Comment: Then `runST` would have a type that depends on `s`, which means that values of type `s` could "escape" from an application `rumST st`. With the `forall` they remain completely opaque.

Answer (score 3):

One immediate utility is with [`TypeApplications`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html) extension, where it allows us to explicitly choose the ordering of type variables:

```
 > foo :: forall a b. a -> b -> b ; foo x y = y
 > :t foo @ Int 1 2
foo @ Int 1 2 :: Num b => b    -- Int goes to the first argument

 > foo :: forall b a. a -> b -> b ; foo x y = y
 > :t foo @ Int 1 2
foo @ Int 1 2 :: Int           -- Int goes to the second argument
```

I couldn't find it mentioned specifically at the link, but the above interaction was tested in repl.it.

Well, actually, the general description at the link does apply: `b` appears *first* in `forall b a. a -> b -> b`, when it is read from left to right.